# Delete unread Yahoo email from a particular sender

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have a Yahoo email account that I do not use much anymore. I have subscribed to a number of list servers that send daily email to that account. Over time (years) a huge number of unread emails have accumulated from these list servers.

1. Is there a way for me to delete unread email from a particular address, i.e., from a particular sender?
   I know I can delete all email from a particular sender, but that is not what I wish to do.  Ideally I could delete only unread email from a particular sender.
   One way would be to select all email from a sender and then scroll through and uncheck those I wish to keep. However, that could take quite a bit of time. Is there a way to automate that process?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to automate deletion of all email from a particular sender after a particular date or between two dates?

Comment: Probably faster if you search the yahoo mail website or contacting the yahoo support people.

Comment: @mdpc: I don't know if I understood your sentence correctly, but a faster way is to search yahoo mail for that sender, select all emails and press delete.

Answer (score 2):

After posting my question I came up with the following:

1. Search for messages from a particular sender.  The result will be Yahoo displays only messages from that sender.  In effect, you are subsetting your email to only those from that sender
2. Then select 'unread' under the square symbol (to the left of the trash can icon).  That will select unread messages from the specified sender, but not unread messages from other senders not specified in Step 1.
3. Now click on the trash can icon.  That will send messages selected in Step 2 to the Trash folder.
4. Note that only the first 100 messages selected in Step 3 will be sent to the Trash folder.  Highlight the Trash folder with your mouse cursor and click on the trash can icon that lights up as the Trash folder lights up.  This trash can icon is different from the trash can icon mentioned in Step 2.
5. You will be asked whether you want to empty the Trash folder.  Click 'okay'.

You will have to repeat this process if you want to delete more than 100 unread messages from a particular sender.